# How to return an object with spyne

Tags: python, spyne

I need to return an object from spyne server method. I read it is possible with **ComplexModel** but this actually has an empty result. What should I do in order to get it working properly?

Here is my code:

```
class Bndbox(ComplexModel):
    xmin = 0
    ymin = 0
    xmax = 0    
    ymax = 0
    def __init__(self, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax):
        self.xmin = xmin
        self.ymin = ymin
        self.xmax = xmax
        self.ymax = ymax

class TestService(Service):
    @srpc(Unicode, _returns=Bndbox)
    def service_method(encoded_string):
        print(encoded_string)
        myBndbox = Bndbox(10, 20, 30, 40)

        print(myBndbox.xmin)
        print(myBndbox.xmax)
        print(myBndbox.ymin)
        print(myBndbox.ymax)

        return myBndbox

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import logging
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.getLogger('spyne.protocol.xml').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    logging.info("listening to http://127.0.0.1:8080")
    logging.info("wsdl is at: http://localhost:8080/?wsdl")

    application = Application([TestService], tns='test_service', in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'), out_protocol=Soap11())
    wsgi_application = WsgiApplication(application)

    server = make_server('localhost', 8080, wsgi_application)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object is empty, as far as spyne is concerned. You can fix it like this:

```
from spyne import Integer64

class Bndbox(ComplexModel):
    xmin = Integer64
    ymin = Integer64
    xmax = Integer64
    ymax = Integer64

    def __init__(self, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax):
        # don't forget to call parent class initializer
        super(BndBox, self).__init__()

        self.xmin = xmin
        self.ymin = ymin
        self.xmax = xmax
        self.ymax = ymax
```